# Can I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows XP on an internal and external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, multi-boot

I've recently gotten a computer with no OS on it.

It has 1 internal and 1 External hard drive.

I have a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it and a copy of windows XP.

Is their a way of installing Ubuntu onto the external hard drive and Windows onto the internal HD so that I can choose which one it should boot from without having to remove the internal HD each time I want Ubuntu, and preferably without having to partition?

Currently the hard drive is blank and un-formatted but the external hard drive has not been made bootable, will this be needed?
Any websites with tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: scratch that, Ubuntu is now on a disk is there still a way I can transfer this to the external hard drive if I made the HD bootable and plugged it into the computer with the ubuntu disk in?

Comment: *yawn* This has been possible for over a decade and there are literally hundreds of viable tutorials and guides online. A quick google would land you somewhere like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot and you'd be on your way. You can definitely install Ubuntu from a bootable USB stick, and the "internal/external"-ness of HDDs has zero impact on whether it is possible to dual boot (answer: **it is** possible, always). Please do a little research (read: google "ubuntu dual boot") before asking a question; thanks!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, My main issue is the fact that it appears i can't select which drive Ubuntu will install to and I will be installing Ubuntu first and this appears to bring about some poblems

Comment: Why can't you select which drive Ubuntu will install to? Every Ubuntu installer I've ever used lets you customize the installation down to the partition level... You might just be using the easy mode instead of telling it to let you customize. I think you have to click an oval like "Something Else" in the new 12.04 version. I don't remember exactly, though. If you post more specifics about what you're trying to do and why it doesn't work, we may be able to help more.

Comment: Addendum: You might like StackExchange's sister site, [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) for user-to-user help specifically about Ubuntu. I'm not proclaiming that your question is off topic for SuperUser; rather, I am telling you that you may be able to get better quality answers from more experienced Ubuntu tech support folks (whether official employees or just dedicated community members) by asking there. I'm only a casual user of Ubuntu; the hardcore community helpers are usually on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Just as proof that AskUbuntu is useful and that I do not in fact dislike your question (sorry if it came off that way), you can check out [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135454/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-seperate-partition) on AskUbuntu which contains detailed instructions for a situation similar to yours (except that you're using separate HDDs and the querant over there is trying to install both OSes on a single disk).

Comment: Ive not attempted it yet, its more that on the ubuntu installation webpage instructions it kept mentioning disk partitions whereas I simply want the two Operating systems installed on completely seperate hard drives, have I misunderstood what a partition is?

Comment: Every hard drive can have one or more partitions. Don't assume that a discussion referring to "disk partitions" means that it's talking about **only one disk** -- that is not the case. You can just as easily set up disk partitions on another disk. But don't think of "partition" meaning "I have to have more than one operating system on the computer"; that is also mistaken. You can have one operating system on one partition on one disk and the partition can occupy up to the entire contents of the disk. You can't, however, install anything without having any partitions.

Comment: A bootloader is the piece of the puzzle that I think you're missing.  It allows you to choose which OS to boot from when the computer starts up.  [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) is a common one.

Answer (score 1):

So after discussing with the querant in the comments, it seems that they were confused by the terminology `partition`.

In computer storage parlance, `partition` refers to a data structure placed on the hard disk which contains a `filesystem`. Partitions can be of any size, from a very tiny size to occupying the entire disk volume. But even if you only want one partition with one operating system on your hard disk, you still need a partition.

So don't think of partitions the way a truck driver thinks of them with a multi-fuel oil tanker. The truck driver thinks they have three partitions (Regular, Plus and Premium grade gasoline) divided by two walls in the middle of the tank. But if the truck driver was only carrying one grade of gasoline, there'd be no need for partitions and they'd have an oil tanker without those dividing walls in the middle. That is **not** how hard disks (or any computer storage media) works.

The Master Boot Record of the hard disk describes the partitions on the disk. Alternately, newer computers use the `GUID Partition Table` instead of the `PC-MBR`, which is a legacy IBM format from the 1980s. The GPT, instead, is much more flexible and supports newer computing technologies and larger capacities, as well as more partitions on a single disk. But the old `PC-MBR` and the `GPT` are both considered to be different *formats* (or types) of Master Boot Record (MBR).

So, **every** useful hard disk has to have some type of MBR, and the MBR defines which partitions are on the disk. Even if you only want one partition with one operating system, you've got to have these things, even if the partition says "I want the whole disk". You can think of a single-partition disk as being the walls of the oil tanker's container itself, spanning the entire volume that the container holds.

The important point to remember is that, in computing, a partition does *not* imply that you must have two or more separate spaces on the hard disk.

Also, as some added insight, be aware that all modern operating systems either require or highly recommend that you use at least two separate partitions. These partitions are often recommended or created automatically by the operating system installer, and the partitions serve different purposes.

On Windows, it often creates an `EFI System Partition` (on new UEFI PCs or Apple Macs) from which to boot, as well as a `System Reserved Partition` which is not normally accessible to users but is used for system infrastructure. It then creates the `System partition` (not to be confused with the `System Reserved Partition` which is where your C:\ drive is, and thus contains all your data as well as the operating system itself.

On Linux, it often creates a moderately-sized `root filesystem` which contains your core operating system files; a very small `boot partition` which contains the Linux kernel and the boot loader (e.g. `GRUB`); a large `home partition` which contains the /home directory and usually occupies the majority of your disk space; and a small `swap space` which is like Windows' page file a.k.a. virtual memory (a complicated topic but let's just say that it is highly recommended to have one but not required).

Partition schemes are, for the most part, arbitrary, and the primary purposes of creating partitions at all are as follows:

1. Allowing different filesystems to be used for different purposes. For instance, on Linux, you might want the `reiserfs` filesystem to be used for your smaller `root partition` due to its fast read performance and efficient use of space on small files, but you might want the `xfs` filesystem on your large `home partition` due to its higher scalability with large amounts of data.
2. Creating a security model for files not intended to be seen/accessed by the user to be hidden away. This is mainly the purpose of Windows' `System Reserved Partition`.
3. Separating out data of different types; for example, the operating system's executable files and data files comprising your programs can reside on the `root filesystem`, while your user's data (documents, music, video, web browser settings, etc) resides on the `home filesystem` -- separation of concerns. That way, in case you want to reinstall your `root filesystem` with a new distribution of Linux, you can retain all of your user's personal data without having to back it up to a separate storage device first.
4. Running multiple operating systems on the same hard disk -- This is fairly obvious, but partitions are almost always required when you want to run two or more separate operating systems from the same physical hard disk.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it doesn't answer the question he posted.

Comment: I interpreted his *actual question* as being very different from the original text of his question, after discussing with him in the comments. So the purpose of my answer was to expound upon a mainly terminological confusion and to explain how partitions are used, and why they're needed. The querant may or may not benefit from this, but from his most recent comment as of this writing, it is apparent that he could use this information. I would invite the querant to edit his original question asking a question that my answer answers, if this answer was educational to him.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install XP on the internal HD
2. Configure /boot/grub.conf or bootloader config and modify /etc/fstab under ubuntu
3. You need to re-install the bootloader on internal HD
4. Whenever you want to login to ubuntu your external HD needs to be connected